# Controller not picking up properties from mixin emberjs

Tags: ember.js, controller

I have some models which share some properties among themselves. The similarities are factored out to mixins.

I try to display some computed properties from the controller, but if the property is from the mixin, the default value is returned in the model. In code in short:

```
var StuffIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    remaining: function(){
        // debugger;
        return this.get('seriousStaff');
    }.property('remaining')
});
```

My model is like:

```
Stuff = Ember.Object.extends(StaffMixin,{
  defprop:''
```

}

My mixin:

```
StaffMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
   seriousStaff: '',
   other: function(){...}.property('other')
}
```

And after creation I populate the model. If on the page I try to display `seriousStaff` I get the empty string, while for `defprop` I get the populated data from the model. The disturbing thing is, that in the template both `seriousStaff` and `defprop` get displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties should have different names from the properties they are observing otherwise you are overwriting your values yourself.

```
StaffMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({ 
    seriousStaff: '',
    other: function(){...}.property('other')
}
```

should be something like

```
StaffMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
       seriousStaff: '',
       other: '',
       computedOther: function(){...}.property('other')
   }
```

Hope this helps.